# Migrating ssrs reports between different domains

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I have an SSRS server in Domain A and i was asked to copy all the folders and reports from domain A to an SSRS server in domain B.

The network team has opened the ports between the two servers in the different domain and i can connect to the web browser of each SSRS from the opposite server.

When i copy reports between server in the same domain i usually user rs service commands. i tried doing the same thing between the two domains and recieved this error:

> could not connect to server http://localhost/[sourceserver]/reportservice2010.asmx

for reference:
server A - is the source server in domain A
server B - is the destination in domain B

this is the command i'm running on CMD:

```
     rs.exe -i ssrs_migration.rss -e Mgmt2010 -s http://[server A IP]/reportserver -u Domain A\username -p domain A password -v f="/foldername" -v ts="http://[server B ip]/Reportserver" -v tu="Domain B\username" -v tp="Domain B password" -v tf="/foldername" -v security="True"
```

also important to mention the the destination server already has reports on it so i cant restore the reportserver DB to it.

what can i do to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue
problem was insufficient permission. used another user and added it to iis_user group and local administrators.
then ran the rs command as usual.
also the cmd needs to run with as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

We have had some good experiences using ReportSync to copy selected folders from one report server to another.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SSRS-How-to-Import-Export-28660d6e

The tool is free and straighforward to use.

Comment: Between domains?

Comment: I haven't tested with multiple domains but assuming you are able to connect to both reports servers from your workstation then it shouldn't be a problem as the tool allows you to specify domain\username as part of credentials for each server